# restart mysqld and php-fpm failed

Tags: mysql

Today our dc restarted server and we got this problem. While starting mysql we seeing this msg

```
systemctl restart mysqld
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
Job for php-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status php-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Have you tried running `systemctl status php-fpm.service` like the error message suggests?

Comment: Please edit the question with the result, not as an answer